# D3.js line chart highest y axis smaller than highest line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For example, in the line the highest value is 890, but the largest axis is 800.

I tried to fix it by change .ticks() and tickSize(), they cannot change highest value. it seems d3 draw it automatically. Is there any way to make the highest value larger than the highest value in chart?

Comment: Try `.nice()` on the scale after setting the domain.

Comment: It doesn't work. just tried

Comment: You can also manually set a higher value.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I'm doing it right now. But is not a good way to do it, because the data change. Currently, I gave it a parameter to set max value, such as 1.2 * 890, it work well here. But when i change value, it doesn't have highest axis, but a large margin at the top.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, what I do is I set it to the nearest 10.

```
yScale.domain(
    [d3.max(dataset) + (
        10 - (
            d3.max(dataset) % 10 )
        )
    ), 0]
```